# php get iscsi output linux

Tags: php, linux, iscsi

I am trying to use exec(), system(), passthru() or anything to read in the output of `iscsiadm -m session`, am not having much luck, and a little lost.

What I (think i) know:

- It is not a sudoers or permission problem, as the results are the same in a terminal or browser (and my sudoers is already successfully setup to use iscsiadm for login/out)
- Executing the following command from a terminal, `iscsiadm -m session > /tmp/scsi_sess` yields an empty `scsi_sess` file

What I need to know:

- Where is the output getting sent, that I can not read it with a bash or php script but can see it in the terminal?
- How can I read the output, or get output sent somewhere that I can read it?

Comment: Check that iscsiadm isn't writing to stderr. Repeat your terminal command line with `2>&1` at the end, which redirects stderr to stdout, and will then send that output to your scsi_sess file.

Comment: Maybe the output is sent to stderr. Try `iscsiadm -m session 2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your syntax you're catching only the stdout. You should redirect the stderr on the stdout with

```
iscsiadm -m session 2>&1 /tmp/scsi_sess
```

Remember, when you do a redirect with `> file` and you still see output, that output is from stderr and not from stdout

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams